# How to not use "We" in about us page?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, writing

We're creating a small web development company. On our site there's an about us page which has a section highlighting our services and portfolio. So there's a lot of text but in a nice organized way.

The about page has a lot of ***we***, for example

> We maintain your project with great care and passion. We stay with you
>   for as long as you need us. We provide long-term support. You can
>   contact us whenever you want and we’ll be there for you.

And that's just one paragraph. I could substitute ***we*** by ***our team***, ***our company***, ***our experts***, ***company name***, etc. But I want to know if there's a better way to do it without having to rewrite every paragraph, without changing the structure of every sentence.

Plus I'd like to keep the sentences humble, I don't want to throw in fancy words like ***company***, ***experts***, ***professionals***.

We are experts, but we're just getting started and since we were independent freelancers we wanted to form a friendly relationship with our clients, now that we're trying to start a company, we want to keep it that way, the reader should not feel like we're bragging or anything like that. That's why there's a lot of ***we***, it's more friendly than the words mentioned above.

And also, I'd like to use something easy to understand, since our clients aren't native English speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way you could accomplish this is to use a conjunction in place of a pronoun. So:

> We stay with you for as long as you need us. We provide long-term support.

becomes:

> We stay with you for as long as you need us and provide long-term support.

Throw in the *our experts* that you suggested in your question, and we’ve cut the number of ***we*** instances in half, from four to two:

> We maintain your project with great care and passion. We stay with you for as long as you need us and provide long-term support. You can contact us whenever you want and our experts will be there for you.

Comment: Another way of doing it would be to use bullet points as in: Our clients may count on us: (.) to stay as long as needed (.) to provide long-term support (.) to be contactable 24 hours a day........ etc

Comment: @RonaldSole - That would be an excellent approach on a web page.